# How can I add text on the left and right of my Panel Title?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap to take away a lot of the CSS work for me. I want to use their Panels for a sort of "Post" by a User. I'd like to have the Title section include Edit/Delete Hyperlinks on the RIGHT side of the Title, while the Title itself is aligned on the left.

I've tried this with no success:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">@vModel.Title <span class="text-right">Hey</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @vModel.Blog
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Title should be aligned on the left (as it does by default) but I want the additional text "Hey" to show up on the RIGHT side.

EDIT:
http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: have you tried using clear: right on the title

Comment: paste code of panel-title and text-right class code. and try to add float:right in text-right class.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap has two class which can help you.

First is `.text-right` and second is `.pull-right` so add this two class and see.

Comment: because pull right is actually floating entire element to the right...where as text-align just setting text into right in specific width of the element.

Comment: I hate float, but this seems to be the best way I've found so far :-(

Comment: Please also adopt the clearfix from @Pangur . Without that the elements which were pulled also were half in the body part

Comment: This caused the background not work for me. @Camille row version worked perfect fine for me!

Answer (score 45):

tiny `clearfix` does it

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         <div class="panel-title pull-left">
             Works fine for me!
         </div>
        <div class="panel-title pull-right">Text on the right</div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel content</div>
</div>
```

You can try it here http://jsfiddle.net/b1Lec5ge/

Comment: Thanks for the clearfix hit. the Layout was really goofy without it :D

Answer (score 4):

Add `float:right` and remove  `text-align: right`

```
.text-right {
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Do not do this! You (almost) never want to work inside the source code of another library. Instead, look if something already exists and otherwise create your own class. In this case, the `.pull-right` class already exists, which does exactly what you made `.text-right` do.

Answer (score 2):

Working solution for question

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-left panel-title">@vModel.Title</div>
            <div class="col-md-8 text-right"><a>hyperlink1</a> <a>hyperlink2</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Each section of panel can hold row(s) with col-xx-xx

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-left">Header left</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-center">Header center</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-right">Header right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">Body left align right</div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-left">Body right align left</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">Footer 1/4 center</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">Footer 2/4 center</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">Footer 3/4 center</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 text-center">Footer 4/4 center</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here you have a snipplet with col-xs-xxx for match *small* screen. Documentation [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-left">Header left</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">Header center</div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">Header right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">Body left align right</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 text-left">Body right align left</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">Footer 1/4 center</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">Footer 2/4 center</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">Footer 3/4 center</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">Footer 4/4 center</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Left and right buttons in panel header. You can replace these buttons with links.

```
<div class="panel-heading text-right">
  <div class="nav"><!-- clears floated buttons -->

    <div class="btn-group pull-left" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"><i class="fa fa-toggle-on"></i>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group pull-right" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </label>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help too. You can use both bootstrap rows and columns to divide the panel into two, like I did here:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">

    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <p>Text on left</p>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <p>Text on right</p>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```